# Odoo Email template to send products

Tags: email, templates, odoo, product, invoice

I need to create an email template to send the SKUs of the products in the message body  and not from the pdf.

Or does anyone know how I can extract the template from the pdf, if possible?

This is the default template

`Dear % if object.partner_id.parent_id: ${object.partner_id.name} (${object.partner_id.parent_id.name}), % else: ${object.partner_id.name}, % endif`

`Here is your % if object.name: invoice $ {object.name}% else: invoice% endif% if object.invoice_origin: (with reference: $ {object.invoice_origin})% endif for the amount of $ {format_amount (object .amount_total, object.currency_id)} from $ {object.company_id.name}. % if object.payment_state == 'paid': This invoice is already paid. % else: Please forward the payment at your earliest convenience. % if object.payment_reference:`

Comment: You can attached your pdf when send mail.

Comment: Yes, this is how it currently works, but they ask me that the body of the email has the same information as the pdf.